# ImGui not linking with glfw3.lib

Tags: glfw, imgui

I had trouble trying to get ImGui working with glfw, I tried everything of what's going on
with the linker to get ImGui working, is there any problems?

[image: Linking error]

I did however tried to look up any related problems with this error, but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: How are you compiling the project?

Comment: I would use x64 to compile it.

Comment: That's the target architecture. Are you using some kind of build system (e.g. make, cmake) or run the compiler directly?

Comment: Ah yes, I used the compiler directly.

Comment: How exactly? Which flags did you use?